# How do I auto-load this specific embedded audio file

Tags: shortcut

I need autoplay the embedded audio from this specific webpage

I will then use that URL within an iOS Shortcut to load this audio news.

From this webpage: https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/av/10318236/headlines-from-bbc-news

I’ve spent some time trying to find the answer in the code but can’t find a way to do this can you please help me solve this problem?

[edit: the main, large image is a clickable media player - I need to automate the equivalent of someone manually clicking on that media player PLAY button - e.g. if you were to just open this webpage and the audio automatically ran - I assume somewhere there is a code instruction to do the PLAY action but I can't find one, due to my limited technical knowledge]

Comment: What code are you refering to?

Comment: Hi Scott - I've just added an edit to the post to clarify, thanks.